# CSS Tabs not growing with content

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have an issue with a web app I'm developing which is to have several tabs for various content. The problem is, the tabs are not growing to wrap the entire content.

CSS Code is here:

```
.w3c {
height: auto;
min-height: 250px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
    .w3c > div {
        display: inline;
    }
    .w3c > div > a {
        margin-left: -1px;
        position: relative;
        left: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        background: white;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }
    .w3c > div:not(:target) > a {
        border-bottom: 0;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #eee);
    }
    .w3c > div:target > a {
        background: white;
    }
    .w3c > div > div {
        background: white;
        z-index: -2;
        left: 0;
        top: 30px;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }                      
    .w3c > div:not(:target) > div {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .w3c > div:target > div {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

And I've built a mockup here: http://jsfiddle.net/diehlada/tx81he5s/

The pages, including the tabs and associated content, for the actual pages are generated on the fly with Catalyst and Template Toolkit. I need the flexibility of being able to generate arbitrary tabs on demand and so the CSS for the tabs cannot include anything specific to any given tab.

I have played around with position: relative; and float: ...; and these inevitably break the tab layout. Also, if I simply remove the inner  that wraps the content, the layout also breaks (although the tab does grow to the content inside). I'm fast running out of ideas and would really appreciate some suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to change the way you are tring to create the tabs. 
I suggest, you should use the jquery tabs.

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

It the most easy and simple way.

I hope it help.

Comment: I'll look into it. I had thought that avoiding javascript would keep things simpler but perhaps not! Thanks!

Comment: Well I've been trying to get it working with Jquery for the past couple hours and am having no luck (argh!)... The example here: http://jsfiddle.net/diehlada/cfwfe04k/ works just fine but when I put the code in its respective places in the actual templates (including the jquery script and css references in the <head>) and try to load it within the app, it's not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Got it working. Oddly, it won't work from local copies of the Jquery codes but will when I link directly to the copies on their server, even though I've verified the local paths are correct. Strange...